# Why Geowebcache is locking all system?

Tags: geoserver, coordinate-system, geowebcache

My story is like this about geowebcache. I am useing geoserver 2.5.x and GeoWebCache version 1.5.2, build 1.5.x. OS is ubuntu.

I can not found geowebcache.xml file in server. But there is a file named **gwc-gs.xml** in **.../geoserver/data/**

I do not use EPSG:4326 and EPSG:900913, I use custom projection named EPSG:987654 and I set it in **epsg.properties** file.

And I created a Grid Set  for custom projection.

1- Should I set all layers Tile Caching settings to my Gridset?

2- When I open demo page of layer geoweb page (`http://localhost:8080/geoserver/gwc/demo/pg:cimy?gridSet=EPSG:987654&format=image/png`) my CPU usage is going %104 and system is locking. After 30-40 second it is normal.

What settings I should do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You change the GEOWEBCACHE_DATA_DIR in web.xml file. After restart service geowebcache.xml will be created.

Demo page creates cache while you are using. So cpu usage is increasing. You can create cache tiles before use the service.